# Python: ufloat to float

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion, uncertainty

I have calculated some ufloats using the [uncertainties package](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/), let's call them theta and gamma.
Now, for my following calculations I don't need their errors (I am using them later as y-values in linear plot).

I simply could calculate them ignoring their errors, but I don't want to do work twice.

i. e. my gamma is `gamma=(42, 0.5)`
I would like to convert them into floats without their errors (so like `gamma_float=42`).
How could I address only their values?

Comment: Do you have a link or reference for those of us who don't know what a "ufloat" is?  It sounds like it is some form of uncertain floating point value.  How are you calculating them?

Comment: DYZ replied the correct solution below. But here is the link: https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/

Comment: Thanks.  I hope you don't mind that I added that link to the question.

Comment: Don't worry, edit as much as you like to improve my question to help others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gamma.nominal_value` is the nominal value of `gamma` (also available as `gamma.n`), and `gamma.std_dev` (also available as `gamma.s`) is its standard variation.